# Binding if a DataGrid column is a tab stop in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGridTextColumn that needs to be a tab stop sometimes, and not a tab stop sometimes.

I have

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SomeColumn">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

And that works just fine in preventing the column from being tabbed to.

I want to do something like

```
<Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="{Binding IsSomeColumnTabStop}" />
```

Where `IsSomeColumnTabStop` is a boolean in the `DataGrid`'s `DataContext`. Unfortunately... this does not work!

I have also tried

```
<Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="{Binding DataContext.IsSomeColumnTabStop}" />
```

But no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this in code behind in a way that feels pretty dirty... binding would definitely be preferred if anybody can point me in the right direction!

In my `DataGrid`'s `Resources` I defined

```
<Style x:Key="TabStopColumn" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="NoTabStopColumn" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```

Then when I want tab stops, I can do...

```
SomeColumn.CellStyle = (Style)MyDataGrid.Resources["TabStopColumn"];
```

And for no tab stops...

```
SomeColumn.CellStyle = (Style)MyDataGrid.Resources["NoTabStopColumn"];
```